# VB.NET Converting Double Value to String = Precision loss

Tags: vb.net, string, double

Hello I have a double value like this in VB.NET:

```
Dim value = 9.729000000000001
```

When converting to string, I get this:

```
value.tostring() "9.729"
```

I try to add formatting:

```
value.tostring("0.00000000000000")
```

But it did not work (I lose the ending 1).

How can I keep all of my digits?

Comment: Problem is only in your format string, ask formatter to pick right representation with `value.ToString("R")` and you'll got it.

Comment: The thing is that when you convert from double to string it gets complete new value.

Comment: @Adriano I deleted my comment because of equisde's answer; actually it is G17 (I was testing G16 and wasn't enough). But the limit is pretty close anyway...

Answer (score 5):

This is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Try this

```
Dim value As Double = 9.729000000000001
Dim strText As String = value.ToString("G17")
```

Or this

```
Dim value As Double = 9.729000000000001
Dim strText As String = value.ToString("R")
```